# jQuery button response time issue while auto refreshing a DIV in every X second

Tags: php, jquery, database, setinterval

I am using this code for refresh my main DIV in my main page (named readings.php):

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function intervalle() {
      setInterval(jQuery('#myMainDiv').load('readings_content.php'), 10000);
});
```

In the readings_content.php, sensor readings are being checked from database and drawing a screen like a security cam screens according to the sensor count. This code is like:

```
$db_sensors->query("select * from tbl_sensors where status=1");
    if ($db_sensors->recordcount>0){
        while ($db_sensors->nextrow()){
        $sensors=$db_sensors->fields;

            $sensorname = $sensors["name"];
            $sensorvalue = $sensors["lastreading"];

        echo "<div>";
        echo "Sensor Name: ".$sensorname."<br>";
        echo "Last Reading: ".$sensorvalue;
        echo "</div>";
    }}
```

This idea is working fine. But because of this loop (there are 9-16 sensors) refresh is taking time. That is normally fine because page is not reloading, just changing the values when it reads a new sensor reading. But there is a button in the my main page (readings.php). It takes almost 10 second for response time for this button even I am using local database.

I want to make this refresh process faster. Or if that is possible, I want to stop this refresh thing (or what ever is happening in the page) when I click the button. and make its onClick event working.

Comment: Are you properly handling sessions in php so that the requests are being handled concurrently rather than synchronously?

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your answer. But I solved the problem some how. And wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my whole researches I started to try all different options. And it only was OK when I change the jQuery code like this:

```
setTimeout('sensorcells_load()', 10000);

function sensorcells_load()
{
    jQuery('#sensorcells').load('dashboard_content.php');
    setTimeout('sensorcells_load()', 10000);
}
```

I am not a jQuery man and I don't really know why this one works but other one doesn't. But this solved my issue.

Comment: I would suggest two changes: replace `'sensorcells_load()'` with `sensorcells_load` in both places, then move the inner setTimeout to inside the complete callback of the .load call. The first change is just a good practice, the second will avoid a stacking request problem if the user or your server has connection problems.